# How do I get the index of the classname selected?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple `input` fields assigned to a particular classname. Now I want to fetch the index of the classname of the `input` field and `console.log()` it.

This is my code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('change', event => {
        console.log(item); //print the index of the item
    })
})
```

How can I do that? Please help me.

Comment: um, forEach has an index.... Question is, do you really need the index? What are you doing with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `forEach()` function allows to define an index variable in order to track each item index. Since the `index` variable mantains its context when call it from the eventListener, you can use it to get the index number:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach((item, index) => {   // Here define the index variable
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
        console.log(index); //print the index of the item
    })
})
```

```html
<button class="class-name">Click index 0</button>
<button class="class-name">Click index 1</button>
<button class="class-name">Click index 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach()` loop takes 2 arguments, the second being optional, and the index. So you could do it like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('change', event => {
        console.log(index); //print the index of the item
    })
});
```

More about the `forEach()` loop [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the index for each

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('change', event => {
        console.log(item, index); //print the index of the item
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class-name').forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('change', event => {
        console.log(index); //print the index of the item
    })
})
```